# Apache Camel - Execute processes before each route

Tags: apache-camel

Following is the route that I have created -

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/abc").routeId("abc").choice()
            // Authenticate the request
            .when(authenticator).endChoice()
            // Authorize the request
            .when(authorizer).endChoice()
            // Validate the request
            .when(abcValidator).endChoice()
            .otherwise()
            .process(abcRequestProcessor).process(storeFeatureRequestDetails).process(featureRequestApproverUpdater).split(body()).process(abcApproverMailer).to("direct:toMail");
```

The above route is functional but I do not want to add the authenticator and authorizer step to each and every route. Is there a way by which I can configure them to run before each route.

I tried the following -

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/*").process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Triggered");
        }
    });
```

but it looks for exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Camel [interceptor](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) API for this...

```
// intercept all incoming routes and log it
interceptFrom().process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Triggered");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put your AAA in every to each and every route why don't you extract their functionality and put them in separate routes and call them inside your route? Example code:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/abc").routeId("abc").choice()
            // Authenticate the request
            .to("direct:authenticator")
            // Authorize the request
            .to("direct:authorizer")
            // Validate the request
            .to("direct:abcValidator")            
            .process(abcRequestProcessor).process(storeFeatureRequestDetails).process(featureRequestApproverUpdater).split(body()).process(abcApproverMailer).to("direct:toMail");
```

Basically the authenticator is now in a separate route. You call it by "direct:authenticator". The same goes for authorize and validate.

This way, if you have other routes that need to use this functionality you just call the AAA routes.

Comment: More or less the same. We will still have to add the to's. Dont we have something like interceptors which are available in struts.

Comment: Search the website and you can find something about interceptors - there is a search box on the Camel front page.